# Direct mapped cache - Small cache block size and high offset

Tags: c, caching, cpu-architecture

I have to deal with different cache block sizes ranging from 4 to 128 for 16-bit words, depending on the cache controller mode. The adresses are 20-bit long with 8 bits for tag, 8 bits for cache memory block ID and 4 bits for offset. The adresses are in hex so they are in a form of 0x0C835, but since the first 4 bits of tag are always zero the microcontroller will receive them as C835. Can someone explain to me how to deal with an offset that is higher than the block size number? For example cache block size of 4 and an offset equal to 8?

Comment: With different cache block-sizes, the number of address bits that form the offset-within-block changes.  (And thus so does the position where the index bits start, and the size of the tag if you have the same number of blocks instead of keeping the total size constant.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have realized now that my task did not ask me to do the impossible and it is actually okay to change the number of offset bits. At least I hope so.